# How to upgrade to 1.13

Tags: upgrade, installation, enterprise-1.13

I have trouble upgrading to 1.13 from 1.12 in the first step it is telling me you should install fresh copy of magento, I installed magento 1.12 and then I want to import the database from my 1.12 to this new fresh one. in the next steps we have the script url_migration_to_1_13 so that to migrate to 1.13.

my question is that shoud I install fresh copy of 1.13 or 1.12?

I am really dissatisfied with [magento documentation.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading)

Upgrading From EE 1.12 or Earlier
Following is a high-level roadmap to upgrade to EE 1.13.0.2 or later from EE 1.12 or earlier. This upgrade involves tasks not required for other Magento upgrades; these new tasks are indicated in the roadmap.

Install Magento in a different directory:

Recommended. Set up a new system (that is, another host) on which to install Magento.
The system should be identical to, if not better than, your current system. The new system must meet the Magento system requirements.
Install Magento in a new, empty root installation directory on the same server.
Important: Do not upgrade Magento in the same directory on the same server because post-upgrade errors are likely to occur.

they are telling identical so I guess it should be 1.12 and not 1.13 but I don't know

Comment: I know the documentation is a bit meh .. but what I believe they mean when they say 'install a fresh copy of magento 1.13' is that you extract the new version into that directory (files), and not run the install script as you import your old versions db into an empty db to which you then point your imported local.xml file.

Comment: so you mean I should install 1.13 and then import db from 1.12 and not run the script?

Comment: yes, you create a new folder with the 1.13 version. Import your media / local.xml / modules and themes and import your old database into a new empty database, edit the local.xml file to point to your new database (to which you have imported the old db export) and the upgrade script will run as soon as you try and load the new shop.

Comment: wow thank you so much I really appreciate it, I will try please make an answer so that I can accept

Comment: Try it first and then post back if it has worked. Regarding the edit in your question: 'identical system' they mean the server setup, not the magento version ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Magento documentation on 'upgrading' is basically saying, install a fresh copy of Magento and migrate your changes and extensions across...  This isn't upgrading and you really don't need to do this.

An absolute must is a safe environment for the developer and store owner to test the upgrade before it goes live, but essentially follow these steps:

- Before doing anything review all of your extensions and upgrade them all to versions listed a compatible with the new Magento version
- Review all local changes with a view to also making these compatible with the new version - have the new version code base to hand to refer to for this.
- Review your admin theme - it's common to make changes directly in the admin theme so compare the admin theme against a clean version of the theme for the current Magento version and note any changes so that these can be re-added in the new Magento version.
- Look for any core files located under the local or community code pools (anything inside a `Mage` directory under `app/code/community/` or `app/code/local/`).  Hopefully the `Mage` directory won't even exist in these locations.
- Very importantly check for core changes under `app/code/core/` and `lib/`.  Again compared against a clean codebase for the current version. Any changes you find move into a module and use preferably an observer to apply them, or if not a rewritten class. If you do find any changes here don't use the developer who made these changes again (yes it's a very clear sign of inexperience and a poor developer in Magento).
- Once this is all done perform the upgrade by dropping the new version fileset over the old fileset.

While these things won't guarantee a clean upgrade, they will set you in good stead for a an upgrade with less fuss that you would otherwise have.  You may well run into issues that need debugging and this is normal for an upgrade of any but the most basic store, but depending on how the store has been developed this may take a while, or it may be quick.  Essentially it boils down to how much more code has been overridden by customisations to the store and whether this core code has changed in the new version.  If it has and the older code your customisations are working with create an issue then you have a bug you need to resolve.

Upgrades are more than a little bit of trial and error when it comes to finding the bugs which may be introduced, but with a well developed store issues should be fewer rather than greater in number.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have so many extensions and extra folders and for sure it will take time, thank you for nice explanation!

Comment: I upgraded but the grid manage products doesn't show up :(

Answer (score 4):

To upgrade from 1.12 to 1.13 you should do the following steps:

**Turn off indexing on your old 1.12 site**

1) Get a backup of you current live database by doing a MySQL dump.

```
mysqldump -uuser -p -hhost database | gzip > backupofdatabase.sql.gz
```

2) Setup a new version of Magento with a fresh version of Magento 1.13.1 (on a new website)
You can then restore your database to a NEW database and run the site against this database

```
gunzip < backupofdatabase.sql.gz | mysql -uuser -p -hhost newdatabase
```

3) You will need to run some post upgrade PHP scripts against your database to update your URLs

```
php -f  shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php
```

Once you have confirmed you can login to your admin and you have no errors you can try with your theme and your modules.

You can see complete instructions here.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading#ee1300-11301-upgrade-to-ee11302-start

Comment: I upgraded but manage products grid doesnt show up

Comment: Does it show up in the default version of Magento (Without any modules?)

Comment: yeah I asked a question here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45221/manage-products-grid-doesnt-show-up1-12-to-1-14-upgrade I can see every thing all the modules and the menue

Comment: I don't really know what the problem is it has been days i didnt have any progress