# manage products grid doesn't show up(1.12 to 1.14 upgrade)

Tags: magento-enterprise

I updated magento 1.12 to magento 1.14 
here is what I did:

```
-create new database
-import old 1.12 database into this new database
-install magento 1.14 by using this database
-run the script of url migration
-run re indexing all the data
-remove cache
-remove sessions
```

I can see grid of attributes but I cannot see the grid of products:
I disabled all modules to see if it is a module conflict but when I did that I hadn't the manage product grid anymore so I think it is a module and a bulit in for magento
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you compare your admin theme to a clean 1.12 admin theme to see if it had been customised?  If so did you port any changeds across to the new 1.14 admin theme?

In situations like this I often view the page source where the grid should be rendering (preferably using something like firebug so you can select elements on screen) and look for where the HTML fails to render further. Inspect the surrounding HTML and track this down to a particular template.  If you are using an IDE and xdebug (which you really should be) then add a breakpoint into the relevant template and step through the code to see where it fails.  This will be your starting point for debugging the issue.

Granted you you don't get so much of an obvious clue in admin as many things (grids included) use common templates, but its still a good starting point.

Comment: you know sometimes when I was in the core and I created a local file and override the core I needed to rename the core file or delete the existing core file if I didn't do it it wouldn't read my overrided local file can it be a case in this new version again?

Comment: I tried to disable all modules and when I disable all modules the catalog menu will go away so itself is a module of magento

Comment: If that was the case then it sounds like you did something wrong.  Classes are looked for in the order `app/code/local/`, `app/code/community/`, `app/code/core/` and finally `lib/`. If you move a `core` file into the equivalent location in the `local` or `community` pool it will always be looked for before `core`.  This is really not an upgrade safe way of doing things, you should instead override core functionality with an observer where possible, or with a class rewrite.  By moving the file you override the entire class not just the methods you need.

Comment: yeah you're right but I exactly overrided on local and it didn't work and I always renamed the corre file and then magento understood ow it is not there I will read the local file :-/

Comment: Jonathan I think you saved my life! I am understanding that it is from custom grid module because manage attributes which is showing up doesn't have problem because it doesnt have custom grid

Comment: omg you did it you did it thank you thank you thank you thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!